# incoming payment for paid application in google play

Tags: android, google-play

i have a developer account to upload android apk , but i have few queries

1. where does the incoming money of paid application falls , in my developer account ?
2. as the application will be paid so how my client gets the incoming money i.e. money which is being paid by the users ? do i need to give access to my developer account or i got to create a new for him ?
3. is there a way to integrate my clients under my developer account and they will get their payment on their google checkout ?

Answer (score 0):

from my experience, you have a merchant account where all the payments goes.

This merchant account has the following details:

-Account holder name:
-Bank name:
-SWIFT code:
-IBAN:

Each month Google makes a payment and the money earned ends up in that account.

Sorry, but I don't think the third option is feasible.

**Added:**
I think the Merchant aacount is strictly connected with 
the Developer Account. So I think you can only have one merchant account each developer account. Anyway,  in settings you have "**User accounts & rights**" 
From there, you can invite users to see your data.

> You are currently the only person who has access to this Developer
>   console.
>
> You can give access to this console to an unlimited number of people.
>   You will remain the owner of this console and will be the only person
>   who can grant or revoke access to other users.

Comment: is it possible to integrate  more then one google merchant account in android developer console ?

Comment: Answering your question I put a section "Added" in my answer.

Comment: i have added integrated Google Merchant from console but didn't get a get an option where i got to save `Account Holder Name` , `IBAN` and other details

Comment: the direct link is this one: https://checkout.google.com/sell/settings?section=Financials Here you have your bank information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple clients then it is better to keep separate Google account for each. So your clients cannot see other application. 
As a developer you can give access to all their accounts so that you can view and check updates.

So each client will have a separate financial details based on their bank.

I don't think you can have multiple financial details in google console. But you can raise your question to google play support team and they will confirm you.