# Multiple Google Merchant accounts for a single Google Play Developer account?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing, android-pay

I am developing an Android application for another company. I would like to release this application under my own Google Play account. The application will have in-app billing.

Can I have multiple Google Merchant accounts, so that in-app payments for one application would go into one account and in-app payments for another application would go into another account? What are other strategies to direct in-app payments for different applications under the same Google Play account into different bank accounts?

Similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783495/incoming-payment-for-paid-application-in-google-play), however there is no definitive answer to the question.

Comment: I think the Google Play Support is the best place to get an aswer to that. You can contact them here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want that you should setup seperate play accounts, or use a script to process the payout report so you know how much money is made where.